# Load image from different server after page loaded

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

In one of my pages, I am loading images generated by Wordpress/mshots, this is making the page load very slow.

What can I do to load this line after the page was loaded?

```
<%= image_tag("http://s.wordpress.com/mshots/v1/http%3A%2F%2F#{project.name}%2F?w=500")%>
```

Update

I modified my code as `cenk ebret` suggested, but still there is no difference, the view is still loading very slowly.

So new question is, how can I load the images, after the page is displayed, because at this point my page is displayed only when everything is loaded.

Answer (score 2):

you can load image with script.

for example:

You have an empty image with this id:

```
<img src="images/empty.png" id="<%=#{project.name}%>">
```

and a script like this:

```
<script>
   $(function(){
       $('#<%=#{project.name}%>').attr('src', '<%= image_tag("http://s.wordpress.com/mshots/v1/http%3A%2F%2F#{project.name}%2F?w=500")%>');
   });
</script>
```

this will work after page load. so, it will not make your page slow.